# Is there any feature extraction methods based on mutual information?

Tags: feature-extraction, information-theory

I got a dataset D={X,y} which have 800 input features and single continuous output. I am looking for any feature extraction methods that satisfy two conditions

(1) Matlab codes are available to download

(2). The method should somehow map input x to transformed input z where z is d vector, (d<<800), such that the mutual information between z_i, and y as high as possible.

I think the methods should relate to CCA, however when perform CCA(X,y) I will obtain vector z that have only one dimension. I hope the methods should have the options to select top d good features like PCA does.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is the framing of the "Information Buttleneck" problem, which can be solved in some cases in EM-like iterative algorithm or heuristically through greedy, agglomerative clustering process.

Useful references:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_bottleneck_method)
- [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0004057.pdf)
- Matlab code: [(1) by G. Chechik](http://ai.stanford.edu/~gal/code.html) or [(2) in the VLfeat library](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/matlab.html)

Indeed it is deeply related to CCA; under certain assumptions on the problem (i.e. Gaussianity) this relation can be made exact (see Wikipedia link and [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/chechik05a/chechik05a.pdf)).

Comment: Hi Uri,
Very helpful suggestion. I really appreciate your help !